# Get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" when running spark project with spark-submit on multiple machines

Tags: object, apache-spark, methods, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm a beginner of scala/spark and I got stuck when shipping my code to the official environment.

To be short, I can't put my SparkSession object in class method and I don't know why? If I do so, it will be fine when I run it on a local single machine but throw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, Could not initialize class XXX` when I package my code to a single jar file and run it on multiple machines using spark-submit.

For example

When I put my code in structure like this

```
object Main{
    def main(...){
        Task.start
    }
} 

object Task{
    case class Data(name:String, ...)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Task").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    def start(){
        var ds = loadFile(path) 
        ds.map(someMethod) // it dies here!
    }

    def loadFile(path:String){
        spark.read.schema(...).json(path).as[Data]
    }

    def someMethod(d:Data):String{
        d.name
    }
}
```

It will give me "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" on each places where I put a self-defined method in those dataset transformation functions (like map, filter... etc).

However, if I rewrite it as

```
object Task{
    case class Data(name:String, ...)

    def start(){
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Task").getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
        var ds = loadFile(spark, path) 
        ds.map(someMethod) // it works!
    }

    def loadFile(spark:SparkSession, path:String){
        import spark.implicits._
        spark.read.schema(...).json(path).as[Data]
    }

    def someMethod(d:Data):String{
        d.name
    }
}
```

It will be fine, but it means that I need to pass the "spark" variable through each of methods that I will need it and I need to write `import spark.implicits._` all the time when a method need it.

I think something goes wrong when the spark try to shuffle my object between nodes, but I don't know how exactly the reason is and what is the correct way to write my code.

Thanks

Comment: SparkSession is a singleton. You don't need to pass it through the method signatures, but you can just use getOrCreate again and get the same object. I suspect part of the problem is that you are creating the sparkSession in the static part of your code. Which jvm are you using? I ran into the occasional problem with OpenJDK, when using scoped case classes.

Comment: Also, I would avoid defining two objects in the same file/class.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to pass `sparkSession` object and import `implicits` in all the methods you need. You can make the `sparkSession` variable as a object variable outside a function and use in all the functions.

Below is the modified example of your code which

```
object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Task.start()
  }
}

object Task{

  case class Data(fname:String, lname : String)
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Task").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  def start(){
    var ds = loadFile("person.json")
    ds.map(someMethod).show()

  }

  def loadFile(path:String): Dataset[Data] = {
    spark.read.json(path).as[Data]
  }

  def someMethod(d:Data):String = {
    d.fname
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for reply but I don't get it? It's almost the same as my version which will give me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error. So I need to add some action like "show()" after transformation? It doesn't make sense?

Comment: No, I need to put my spark definition inside the "start()" method otherwise it keeps give me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError no matter I "show()" it or not and I didn't know why :(

Comment: Just the same as your version with different file path. I'm pretty srue the data loading part is OK since I can show the data without problem, the problem happened when I called map and put my self-defined function in it

Comment: I already made a small and clean project as this to rule out other possible problems. And it only happened when I run my code in my AWS-EMR using one master and four slave nodes, it worked fine on my local single core computer.

Comment: The interesting thing is, if I write anonymous function like ds.map(x => x.fname), it is ok!.

Comment: That is strange!!